# XamarinのiOSによるTimer監視下における画像表示について

Tags: ios, xamarin

IISサーバー側にて数秒内で
１〜７枚作成される画像をXamarinのiOSにて表示しようとしています。
Androidは表示できたのですが、
iOSは何故かうまくいきません。
手法は単純でタイマーで監視し経過したら
サーバー内のHTTPアドレスを見に行く感じです。
Android版の方では特に問題なく表示します。
何故かiOSになると表示されません。
何か原因があるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

```
using System.Timers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Assd1Tab.Views
{
    public partial class ReceiveDataPageiOS : ContentPage
    {
        /// <summary>Timer用コントロール</summary>
        public Timer Timer1 { get; set; } = null;
        
        public ReceiveDataPageiOS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timer1 = new Timer();
            Timer1.Interval = 1000;
            Timer1.Start();
            Timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerEvent);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// タイマーイベント
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnTimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image1.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic0.Jpeg";
            Image2.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic1.Jpeg";
            Image3.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic2.Jpeg";
            Image4.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic3.Jpeg";
            Image5.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic4.Jpeg";
            Image6.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic5.Jpeg";
            Image7.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic6.Jpeg";
            Image8.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic7.Jpeg";
            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// コンテンツロードイベント(このフォーム呼び出し時のイベント)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ContentPage_Appearing(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Image1.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic0.Jpeg";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// コンテンツアンロードイベント(このフォーム消去時のイベント)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ContentPage_Desappearing(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void ContentPage_LayoutChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Assd1Tab.Views.ReceiveDataPageiOS"
    Appearing="ContentPage_Appearing" Disappearing="ContentPage_Desappearing" LayoutChanged="ContentPage_LayoutChanged">
    <ContentPage.Content >
        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Grid x:Name="ReciveGrid" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="Image1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image4" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image5" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image6" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image7" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Image x:Name="Image8" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

以下の様にTimerイベントの箇所を編集したらiOS版は動作致しました。

```
private void OnTimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Image1.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic0.Jpeg";
        Image2.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic1.Jpeg";
        Image3.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic2.Jpeg";
        Image4.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic3.Jpeg";
        Image5.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic4.Jpeg";
        Image6.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic5.Jpeg";
        Image7.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic6.Jpeg";
        Image8.Source = "http://192.168.0.10/Pic1/Pic7.Jpeg";
    });
}
```